# Jackson serialization error when class has generics in it

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

So I have a class that I want jackson to serialize.

```
public class MyClass<T extends MyInterface> {

   private T myGeneric;
   private String desc;

   ....
}

public interface MyInterface {
   String getSomeString();
}

public class MySubClass implements MyInterface {
  private String info;
  ....

  @Override
  public getSomeString() {
     return "";
  }
}
```

`MyClass` can have many types of other classes under it's `myGeneric` field.
The problem is that when I pass my JSON to the server, then Jackson throws an error: `problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information`.

I investigated around and mostly only found examples of how to solve jackson problems with abstract classes but none for this kind of problem. I also tried using the `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubTypes` annotations to list what kind of classes can go under `MyClass` but I am not sure if what I did was just wrong or not because it is hard to find any similar examples with them and the documentation in [here:](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.html?is-external=true) was not really helpful also.

Is this kind of problem solvable with Jackson annotations or I need to write a custom serializer for my class?

I am testing the serialization like this:

```
String json = "myJson";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyClass myClass = mapper.readValue(json, MyClass.class);
```

Comment: What does your mapper call look like?

Comment: mapper.readValue(json, MyClass.class).

Comment: Updated question with testing code. My Json is really big so I did not input the actual json there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jackson can't deserialize abstract types without additional info: when you have JSON with field

```
"myGeneric" : { "field1" : 1, "field2" : 2}
```

you have no idea what is the class of the `myGeneric` object.

So you have two options: use `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation or to create custom deserializer. Example:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@class")
private T myGeneric ;
```

After that, serialized `myGeneric` field will look something like that:

```
"myGeneric" : { "field1" : 1, "field2" : 2, "@class" : "com.project.MySubClass"}
```

Deserializer will use this info to instantiate an object of correct type

Comment: So this means I have to pass the name of the class with my json under @class key?

Comment: @Kaspar no, if you use annotations, jackson framework should handle it on its own - I'll update the answer a bit